# PDF PRINT ISSUE

Tags: pdf, printing, pdfbox

I'm using pdfbox-app-2.0.11.jar to generate pdf using java in Liferay 6.2. 
It's give's me output successfully but when I get print out of that print data get removed from pdf.

My-finding: I check all printer regarding solution but not able to get out it.

I think it's issue regarding api which I'm using ethier metada issue.

Comment: Please retry with the current version, which is 2.0.14. If it still doesn't work, please share your PDF. Also try with a different printer (e.g. xps). And clarify what you mean with "that print data get removed from pdf" and clarify whether you are printing with PDFBox or with Adobe.

Comment: I tried with 2.0.14 verion but note working.  no any issue found regarding pdfbox api.i'm not able to share that pdf. is there any other solution

Comment: I still don't know what you meant with "that print data get removed from pdf" and I still don't know whether you are printing with PDFBox or with Adobe. I'd love to help but I can't as long as you're not telling what the problem is.

Comment: If your problem is that parts of the text is missing in print, then try using the `dpi` parameter of `PDFPrintable`. This renders to image before printing.

Comment: issue has been resolved. problem was in PDF property settings. That is "visible but don't print" property which was set as dont print. Now i have updated to visible which will print. thanks for help

Comment: Glad to hear that. It sounds like a problem with annotations. I suggest you delete your question or answer it yourself to help others (include the code), in that case please do also edit your question to mention that it is about annotations (if my guess is correct).

Comment: I'm level of fressers so write wrong but thank you so much Tilman for your valuable time.